# How to find the kernel boot parameter for a given boot configuration option?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, smbios

I have a Dell laptop running Debian Sid. Current kernel (4.15.4) is configured to load `dell_smbios` as module (`CONFIG_DELL_SMBIOS=m`). This produces the followning error while booting

```
dell_smbios: No dell-smbios drivers are loaded
```

I want to add a kernel boot parameter to stop dell-smbios from being loaded. Something like `dell_smbios=off` (Used to diable ACPI, i.e `acpi=off`) or `dell_smbios.disable=1` (Used to disable IPv6, i.e `ipv6.disable=1`).

So how do I know the specific kernel boot parameter for a given configuration option in the config file in `/boot` directory?

Comment: Try adding `modprobe.blacklist=dell_smbios` or `module_blacklist=dell_smbios` as boot parameter.

Comment: Just because the option is selected to configure a driver as a module does not necessarily mean it is being loaded. In fact, the error message seems to suggest to me that the module is, in fact, *not* being loaded ("no drivers are loaded"). I think the problem needs to be clarified: is the module being loaded when it shouldn't be, or is it not being loaded, when it should?

Comment: Is it causing any actual problems, once the system is up and running, aside from the boot log message?

Comment: @Time4Tea Yes exactly -- I can `modprobe i915` any time I have realized. I do NOT get a "warning" when I boot without, but that actually wouldn't be wrong when I see the importance of this (intel-) GPU/DRM module.  Probably that Dell-SMB module is also a bit special.

Answer (score 1):

Since it’s configured as a module, you should blacklist it. To do so, create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d`, named for example `dell-smbios.conf`, containing

```
blacklist dell_smbios
```

You might need to update your initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```